# Select When Statement in SAS

Tags: sas

I would like to create a new column and assign a value based on combination of 3 variables. for example, If Battery Life is 4, RAM (GB) is 3 and HD Size (GB) is 40  then assign 80 in new variable 'Laptop_Class'. There are other combinations as well. How do I do that using proc SQL in SAS?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in PROC SQL, but a Data Step will be less code and more intuitive.

```
data have;
set have;

if battery_life = 4 and ram = 3 and hd_size = 40 then
   new_var=80;
else if .... then
...
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL alternative to data step if/then is CASE WHEN

```
proc sql;
    create table test as select
        t1.*,

        case 
            when t1.battery_life = 4 and t1.ram = 3 and t1.hd_size = 40 then 80
            when ......... then 70
            when ......... then 60
        end as new_column

    from source_table t1;
quit;
```